# PHP trouble with accessing array string elements

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am having a really hard time accessing the element of an array and cant figure out why. I am sure its something silly. Any help would be appreciated.

I `var_dump($employerInfo);`

and get

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#1920 (18) { 
        ["id_professional"]=> string(3) "116" 
        ["pro_fname"]=> string(5) "firstname" 
        ["pro_lname"]=> string(5) "lastname" 
        ["pro_email"]=> string(18) "email@example.org" 
        ["pro_pwd"]=> string(32) "xxxxx" 
        ["pro_company"]=> string(27) "Example company name" 
        ["date_sub"]=> string(19) "2021-02-08 13:34:00" 
        ["pro_enabled"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["pro_title"]=> string(25) "Title" 
        ["pro_address"]=> string(33) "123 main street" 
        ["pro_address2"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["pro_state"]=> string(2) "CA" 
        ["pro_city"]=> string(5) "city" 
        ["pro_zipcode"]=> string(5) "12345" 
        ["pro_phone"]=> string(14) "(123) 456-7360" 
        ["pro_extension"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["pro_fax"]=> string(1) "-" 
        ["pro_website"]=> string(31) "https://www.examplesite.com/" 
    } 
}
```

So I want to access only the `pro_company` and therefore I use

`echo($employerInfo[1]);` but get the error  "UUndefined offset: 1 in ..."

so see its not an indexed array then I moved to trying to access via the object selector - `echo($employerInfo->pro_company)` but that gets the error -  "Trying to get property 'pro_company' of non-object in ....."

What is the solution to access this?

Comment: `$employerInfo` only has one element, it's index is `0`.

Comment: `$employerInfo[0]->pro_company`

Comment: ah thank you. I must have had another error elsewhere because I had tried that too and got the undefined index. So I better understand, why is the index needed when there is only one element?

Comment: It's still an array. You have to use the index to distinguish between operating on the array element and the array itself.

Comment: @barmar makes much sense. Thank you. Not that you need the reputation points but if you want to put that as an answer, it might help people and I can accept it. Before posting my question, I looked around SO for a bit but couldnt find anything similar as an explination

Comment: I voted to close the question as a typo, it's not worth answering.

Answer (score 0):

This might be able to help other people since the reasoning behind the answer is harder to find on SO than one might think. The index must be referenced here even though there is only one element in position [0]. Thus you need
 `$employerInfo[0]->pro_company`